# definit integral of Airy function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, airy-functions

How can I evaluate this definite integral

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Ai}^2(z+a_n)}{z^2}dz $$
where $a_n$ are the zeroes of the Airy function.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there are closed-form expressions for these?

Comment: Yes I think so,